# How Get Header Item in qwik and Qwik City

Tags: qwik

I am set  an item called **Local** in the header in **NGINX config** but this item or other items that I set, but none of the items in `requestEvent` Does not exist

**My nginx config**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.local;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    server_name example.local;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    ssl_certificate /Temp/example/SiteQwik/Certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /Temp/example/SiteQwik/Key.pem;

    location / {      
        proxy_pass http://localhost:89696;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        rewrite ^/(?<locale>\w\w)(/.*)$ $2 break;
        proxy_set_header Locale $locale;
    }
}
```

***Qwic code***

```
import { component$ } from '@builder.io/qwik'
import { routeLoader$ } from '@builder.io/qwik-city'

const getData = routeLoader$(async (requestEvent) => {
    console.log('Request headers:', requestEvent.headers);
    const data = {
     title = test
    }
    return data
})

const Contact = component$(() => {

    const data = getData().value   

    return <>
      <h1>Hello World </h1>
    </>
})

export default Contact
```

But my output is something like this ‍‍‍

```
Request headers: HeadersList {
LearningLandSiteQwik |   cookies: null,
LearningLandSiteQwik |   [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(0) {},
LearningLandSiteQwik |   [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
LearningLandSiteQwik |

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
`requestEvent.request.headers` in your routeLoader$